# Break a for loop that is prompting input to list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple program that accepts input of 'sales amounts' individually for each day of the week then totals the values and displays them.
I have a loop that accepts 7 inputs, but I would like the user to be able to enter `'q'` to break the loop if they have less than 7 inputs.
Here's what I have:

```
sales = []
for i in range(0, 7):
    sales.append(input("> "))
    if 'q':
        break
```

It is giving me a `NameError`, but I've tried a variety of things.
I've done `if sales/input/raw_input == "q":`.
I've also set `q` equal to a variable, but that terminated my loop after one iteration.

Comment: `if 'q':` will *always evaluate truth-y*. If you want to evaluate the last item entered, it's `sales[-1]`; `sales` is the list, `input` is a function and `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3. Or check it *before* you put it into the list.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean. As far as `input` vs. `raw_input` in Python 3, I am aware that it no longer exists, but the environment I'm working in is still treating it differently. (Yes, I am definitely using 3 and it definitely handles it differently than `input`. I double checked these again before posting this comment.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store the input in a variable so you can reuse it without requiring the user to re-enter the value

```
user_input = input("> ")
if user_input == "q":
    break
sales.append(user_input)
```

Comment: I am still getting a `NameError` with that structure.

Comment: @ohheyhannah then please give a [mcve] because this seems correct to me. Are you sure you're using 3.x?

Comment: Yes, I am using 3.5

Comment: I actually was able to use the above code but with `raw_input` to get a step further before an error so I'll accept the answer. (I swear I'm using 3; I can screenshot for proof because I'm sure this is strange.) Thank you